# ¿Por qué en firefox no me funciona el proxy reverse o gateway configurado con Apache?

Tags: firefox, apache2

Tengo tres servicios que corren a la par:

- **Moodle**: en *127.0.0.1*
- **Un backEnd en wildfly**: *localhost:8080/sitio*
- **Un frontEnd en Angular 4**: *localhost:4200*

He configurado un gateway con ***Apache*** de la siguiente manera:

- EL archivo **000.default.conf:**

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ProxyServer

      ProxyRequests Off

      <Proxy *>

      Order deny,allow

      Allow from all

      </Proxy>

      ProxyPass "/pagina" "http://127.0.0.1/" 
      ProxyPassReverse "/pagina" "http://127.0.0.1/"

      ProxyPass "/api" "http://localhost:8080/sitio"
      ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://localhost:8080/sitio"

      ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:4200/"
      ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:4200/"
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- El moodle tengo corriendo en mismo servidor Apache, su configuración:
  **pagina.conf**:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName Server

      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /home/user/path-to-the-moodle

      <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
      </FilesMatch>
      <Directory />
              Options FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride None
      </Directory>
      <Directory /home/user/path-to-the-moodle>
              DirectoryIndex index.php
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Require all granted
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

He habilitado los ***modulos***, ***proxy***, ***proxy_html***, ***proxy_http***, y ***proxy_wstunnel*** (este no es necesario según leí).

Me carga exitosamente la página en Chrome, Chromium y Opera. Es decir, accedo en `localhost` y redireje a `localhost:4200`

Pero en Firefox salta 404 not Found para `localhost/algo` y `localhost/pagina`. 
Y si accedo a `localhost` redirecciona a `127.0.0.1` que es la página de ***moodle***, debería haber sido `localhost:4200`.

Ya he leído las  recomendaciones de Mozilla pero no me han funcionado

¿Por quá puede ser?